# tftp-hpa does not start when i run /etc/init.d/tftp-hpa start

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upstart, systemd, tftp

I've a question because I found a bug, on Ubuntu 14.04 when i run :

```
/etc/init.d/tftp-hpa start
```

my tftp server does not start. Because this script can be runed only by systemd and not by upstart.

But when y run :

```
service tftp-hpa start
```

My tftp server start 
have you any idea of which script is launched by service tftp-hpa start ?

Comment: Are you quite sure that this is Ubuntu _14.04_? And this is most likely off topic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`service tftp-hpa start` uses `/etc/init/tftpd-hpa.conf` (upstart configuration) which uses `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` as configuration file.